# Textarea loses focus when calling a function

Tags: javascript, jquery, html

What I'm trying to achieve is to read the current word at the caret position.

Example:

> Hello| -> returns Hello
>
> Hel|lo -> returns Hello

I have put the code inside an event handler which is onKeyup inside an if statement:

```
if( e.keyCode === 37 || e.keyCode === 39 ){
  console.log($(this).getWord());
}
```

When this is executed, it returns the current word, but the text area loses the focus.

[Jsfiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/7g4rjLsq/)

**How is this supposed to work**?

Type word in the text area then click on left or right arrow keys, the current word will get displayed.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

I would use `textArea.selectionStart` instead of mucking with mutating the selection itself. This will work for you if Internet Exploder < 8 compatibility isn't a concern.

```js
var $mytextarea = $('#mytextarea');

$mytextarea.keyup(function(e) {
  if (e.keyCode === 37 || e.keyCode === 39) {
    $("#current").text(getWord());
  }
});

function getWord() {
  var textarea = $mytextarea[0],
    pos = textarea.selectionStart,
    raw = textarea.value,
    start = pos,
    end = pos;

  while (raw.charAt(start) !== ' ' && start > 0) {
    start--;
  }
  while (raw.charAt(end) !== ' ' && end < raw.length) {
    end++;
  }

  return raw.substring(start, end);
}
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<textarea id="mytextarea">The quick brown fox jumps over the lazy dog.</textarea>
<div>

  the current word is <span id="current"></span>
</div>
```

Answer (score 3):

I changed your code a bit. It no longer manipulates the cursor which means response time is a lot faster.

Here is your updated code:

```js
$('#mytextarea').keyup(function (e) {
    //if (e.keyCode === 37 || e.keyCode === 39) {
  
        //get cursor position
        var caret = getCaretPosition(this);
        //get the end index of current word
        var endOfWord = this.value.slice(caret.end).match(/(\s|$)/i).index + caret.end;
        //get current word
        var word = /\S+$/.exec(this.value.slice(0,endOfWord));
        //make sure word is not null
        word = word ? word[0] : '';
        //remove punctuation
        word = word.replace(/(\.|\!|,|;|:|\(|\)|\{|\}|\[|\]|'|"|-$)/,'');
        $("#current").text(word);
  
    //}
});

function getCaretPosition(ctrl) {
    var start, end;
    if (ctrl.setSelectionRange) {
        start = ctrl.selectionStart;
        end = ctrl.selectionEnd;
    } else if (document.selection && document.selection.createRange) {
        var range = document.selection.createRange();
        start = 0 - range.duplicate().moveStart('character', -100000);
        end = start + range.text.length;
    }
    return {
        start: start,
        end: end
    }
}
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>

<textarea id="mytextarea"></textarea>
<div>
  the current word is <span id="current"></span>
</div>
```

I do want to point out this is not my code and was copied from [this fiddle](http://fiddle.jshell.net/gANLv/1/).

Comment: I updated the code and fixed all the bugs. I commented out the keycode filter just because I wanted to see how it would look if it updated every key you typed.